# Order by date wise report?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Order by date wise report problem

```
select 
    liftingbirds, totalweight, avgweight, dcno,
    convert(varchar,liftingdate,103) as liftingdate 
from 
    k_LiftingEntryRecords 
where 
    dcno = @dcno 
order by 
    liftingdate desc
```

Here I am not getting order wise date report ...when I remove where condition 
`dcno = @dcno`, then it comes order wise date report...

```
select 
    liftingbirds, totalweight, avgweight, dcno,
    convert(varchar,liftingdate,103) as liftingdate 
from 
    k_LiftingEntryRecords 
order by 
    liftingdate desc
```

other wise it's not come.. like

Comment: Is your liftingdate column type is datetime?

Comment: yes,liftingdate column is datetime..

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Your sort will be chronological (before the newest date and then the older). If you want an alphabetical sort, you must change your sortered field with a convert field (as in select field list)

Answer (score 1):

`varchar` is a string not a date. String comparison in sql server is done alphabetically which is very different to ordering by a date data type. Let me know If you understand the difference otherwise I'll expand my answer

Comment: order by is on date, the output field is string

Comment: @JoeTaras `order by` operates on select expressions. He is ordering by `liftingdate` which has been define as part of the result set in the `select` statement as an alias. Notice the `as` in the `convert` expression. The result of this expression is a `varchar`

Comment: liftingdate is too the name of field! Our OP must change the name, do you think for better readeable?

Comment: Exactly,if he wants to order by the original column then he should alias the table (in the `from` clause) and use the alias in the `order by` clause